# Merging slices of structs

Tags: json, go, slice

I'm attempting to merge two different json array's of structs together into one json blob (from separate pagination requests). I'm however, unable to merge them together:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "log"
)

func main() {
  superset := `[{"id": 1231, "name": "testing1"},{"id": 1235, "name": "testing2"}]`
  subset   := `[{"id": 1237, "name": "testing3"}]`

  s, _ := json.Marshal(superset)
  log.Printf(string(s))

  u, _ := json.Marshal(subset)
  log.Printf(string(u))

   for i := range s {
     u = append(u, s[i])
   }

   log.Printf(string(u))
}
```

However, that gives me really just the concatenation of them:

```
"[{\"id\": 1237, \"name\": \"testing3\"}]""[{\"id\": 1231, \"name\": \"testing1\"},{\"id\": 1235, \"name\": \"testing2\"}]"
```

I'm hoping for an output that looks like:

```
[{"id": 1237, "name": "testing3"},{"id": 1231, "name": "testing1"},{"id": 1235, "name": "testing2"}]
```

I feel like I'm missing something silly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) marshals the given value into JSON (and returns it as a `[]byte`), so what you have in `s` and `u` are JSON texts holding your input JSON texts. Appending (concatenating) these 2 texts will not even result in valid JSON, obviously not what you want.

Your inputs are JSON texts, holding a JSON array. So what you should do is unmarshal your inputs into Go slices (of type `[]interface{}`), which you can append, then marshal the result back to JSON.

Something like this:

```
superset := `[{"id": 1231, "name": "testing1"},{"id": 1235, "name": "testing2"}]`
subset := `[{"id": 1237, "name": "testing3"}]`

var s1, s2 []interface{}

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(superset), &s1); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(subset), &s2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

s2 = append(s2, s1...)

result, err := json.Marshal(s2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(result))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jeHriipkmph)):

```
[{"id":1237,"name":"testing3"},{"id":1231,"name":"testing1"},{"id":1235,"name":"testing2"}]
```

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for the explanation as well!